# Will an LCD monitor limited to 50Hz affect my experience?

Tags: multiple-monitors, refresh-rate

I'm considering buying this from Matrox that will allow me to connect multiple monitors to my Macbook Pro.

- http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/displayport/

The small print says the output is limited to 50Hz. Is this likely to affect my experience? I'm using it for (web designer / developer) so I'm not too bothered about computer games or movies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general use it will be more than fine. 50Hz is the refresh rate of the monitor and it just means that you will be limited to 50 Frames Per Second (FPS). You don't need to worry about FPS when developing as the environment will remain relatively static.